# Alternative to POI's getCellNum method

Tags: java, maven, apache-poi

I am working on a legacy system that uses the getCellNum method in

```xml
<groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
<artifactId>poi</artifactId>
<version>3.11</version>
```

its usage:

```java
private void setValue(BpShipment entity, HSSFCell cell) {
    if (cell != null) {
        int cnum = cell.getCellNum(); // not found error
        // the rest of the code
```

When I started using the newer POI version on some new code

```xml
<groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
<artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
<version>3.17</version>
```

I started having an error in the legacy code saying that getCellNum() can't be resolved.
Does any one know what is the replacement for getCellNum in the newer POI versions ?

***Note:***

Both legacy code class and new code class exist in the same maven project, so I can only use one of the POI dependencies, or can I use both?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's listed in the [deprecated list](http://javadox.com/org.apache.poi/poi/3.13/deprecated-list.html):

`org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell.getCellNum(`)
          (Oct 2008) use [`HSSFCell.getColumnIndex()`](http://javadox.com/org.apache.poi/poi/3.13/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFCell.html#getColumnIndex())